# state_interfaces_ empty in custom ros2_control controller

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a simple state broadcasting controller, I used the joint state broadcaster as a template.
The inherited state_interfaces_  vector is empty in the controller when I try to validate the interfaces in on_config.

I have setup the interfaces in the ros2_control plugin and set the names in state_interface_configuration in the controller.
I have put debug trace in both the command and sate configuration functions but I don't see the trace running.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413001/state_interfaces_-empty-in-custom-ros2_control-controller/) by [neuromancer2701](https://answers.ros.org/users/43257/neuromancer2701/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2023-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The inherited state_interfaces_ is not available until on_activate and that is based on if the correct state interfaces that are setup in state_interface_configuration which takes place after on_config.

---

Originally posted by [neuromancer2701](https://answers.ros.org/users/43257/neuromancer2701/) with karma: 71 on 2023-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0